# WebSocket Integration with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket

I'm currently using [`em-websocket`](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket) for an application I'm writing that has a live feed.  The problem I'm running into now is that certain info associated with a user account is needed to subscribe a client to the right feed, meaning I need to have access to the session data.  Because the WebSocket server runs in a separate process and doesn't have access to this data, I need to find some workaround.

There is [`websocket-rails`](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails), but the project seems to be abandoned and I'm not entirely sure about using abandonware in production.

Is there a good example of an application that uses WebSockets and Rails at the same time?

Comment: I suggest using the Rails 5 RC 1.  They just added ActionCable which features a teriffic websockets integration.  DHH has a great video on how to use it at https://medium.com/@dhh/rails-5-action-cable-demo-8bba4ccfc55e#.sygrm5ldp

Comment: @HarperMaddox It looks like action cable works with 4.2.3, which means I can just use it out of the box!  I'll go with that.

Comment: Awesome!!! Post back how it works for you.  I haven't tried it, but the video makes it seem great.

Comment: @HarperMaddox I'm running into an issue with puma after following the guide - it says there's "no application to run."  I have no idea what that means, and I've done everything the guide tells me to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Thin as your server, [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) can be added as a Rack app. https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby

There's also a rails helper: https://github.com/jamesotron/faye-rails

Faye has detailed [security and authentication information](http://faye.jcoglan.com/security/authentication.html) although not directly rails related. Most seem to use the CSRF token from Rails as the link.

Answer (score 1):

Rails stores the session data in an "encrypted" cookie... This is a "good enough" solution, but I would avoid storing any sensitive information over there.

[The Rails API also allows you to decode the session cookie manually](https://gist.github.com/zettabyte/1052112) (look it up, it isn't that difficult, but it is version dependent). This means that you can access the Rails session data by accessing the raw encrypted cookie (but I wouldn't set the data that way).

You could also use a customized short-lived (usually one-time) "token" cookie that will be used by the websocket connection to initialize any authentication data related to the websocket.

I don't know if `em-websockets` gives you access to cookies, but I know that the [Plezi framework](http://www.plezi.io] offers you both access to cookies and a local session storage (which might be somewhat safer, but cookie hijacking is always a risk).

You can easily [integrate Plezi websockets with Rails, as mentioned here](http://www.plezi.io/docs/with_rack_app).